# Emulate "su root" command to fix Permission Denied error

Tags: android, delphi

I am developing a program for Android in Delphi.

In a terminal, I tested the next commands:

```
su root
echo 1 > /sys/class/port/export 
echo 1 > /sys/class/port/port1/value
```

It works without problem.

In Delphi, I created the next code and added my program to Android as a root program.

```
TFile.WriteAllText('/sys/class/port/export', '1');
TFile.WriteAllText('/sys/class/port/port1/export', '1');
```

After run, I received an error:

> Permision Denied

How to emulate the **su root** command before calling `WriteAllText`?

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to stimulate activity in accordance with my task in this forum? Сan I offer a bonus?